# PHP - Enviar para outra página id do cliente ao clicar em uma celula

Tags: php, html, css

Tenho uma lista clientes cada um em uma célula.

Quero, ao clicar na célula, enviar para outra página o `id` do cliente selecionado, de forma segura. Sem mostrar o id no link.

Gerando as tabelas:

```
$marcador = '<img src="../imagens/traco.png" width="5px" height="13px"> ';
//Iniciando tabela
        echo '<table>';
        //Mostrando em uma tabela
        foreach ($clientes as $cliente) {
            //Linha da tabela
            echo '<tr>';
            //Celula da tabela
            //Nome do cliente, recebe cor diferente
            echo '<td><a href="meuendereco/outrapagina"><span class="nome">' . $cliente->getNome() . '</span><br>'
            . $cliente->getFantasia() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . 'Cód.: ' . $cliente->get_id() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . $cliente->getEnderco() . ', ' . $cliente->getNum() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . $cliente->getBairro() . ' - ' . $cliente->getCidade() . ', ' . $cliente->getUf() . '</a></td>';
        }
```

Meu *CSS*
Pelo meu *css* fiz com que uma célula seja como um link.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* CORPO DA PÁGINA */
body {
 color:#666;     /* cor padrão para todas fontes */
 font-weight: bold;  /* negrito */
}

/********************* TABELA **********************************/
/* linha da tabela*/
table, td {
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-top: 3mm;      /* distancia do topo */
 padding-bottom: 1.5mm;    /* distancia da base*/
 border-collapse: collapse;   /* Borda simples */
 border-bottom: 1px solid green; /* Borda de baixo */
 border-bottom-color: #666;   /* cor da borda de baixo */
 
}
/* espaço da celula */
td:hover{
 background: #C6E2FF; /*cor de fundo da celula*/   
 cursor: pointer;  /*cursor na celular será uma mãozinha*/
}
/* link na célula */
td a{
 text-decoration:none;   /* texto não ficará sumblinhado na tabela*/
 display: block;   /* link será na célula */
 height: 100%;     /* link será em toda célula*/ 
 color:#666;    /* a cor do texto será (cinza)*/   
}
/******************* FIM - TABELA ******************************/

/* cor do nome dos clientes*/
.nome {
 font-size: 18px;  /* tamanho da fonte */
 color:#6699CC;    /* cor da fonte */
 font-weight: bold;   /* fonte em negrito */
}
```

Comment: Na linha 10 do código q vc postou, passe o *ID* do cliente por `GET` dessa forma `<a href="meuendereco/outrapagina?cliente_id=' . $cliente->get_id() . '">`

Comment: Só que assim o id é visível no link. Quero evitar isso. Tem outra forma?

Comment: Na verdade isso não é muito problema não, pq mesmo enviando por `POST` é possível ver os dados enviados no *request*, mas se isso faz muita diferença pra ti, use um `form` em cada célula que seja possível enviar o id para a outra página.

Comment: Por que você quer esconder o ID do cliente? Qual é a ameaça contra a qual você quer se defender?

Comment: Tem razão, não preciso esconder o ID do cliente, mas caso eu precise, farei um forme na célula mesmo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um `form` em cada célula e enviar cada por `POST` o `id` do cliente

```
echo '<td><form action="meuendereco/outrapagina" style="display:none;" method="post" name="post_' . $cliente->get_id() . '" >
        <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="' . $cliente->get_id() . '">
    </form>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.post_' .  $cliente->get_id() . '.submit();">' . $cliente->getNome() . '</span><br>'
            . $cliente->getFantasia() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . 'Cód.: ' . $cliente->get_id() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . $cliente->getEnderco() . ', ' . $cliente->getNum() . '<br>'
            . $marcador . $cliente->getBairro() . ' - ' . $cliente->getCidade() . ', ' . $cliente->getUf() . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: Falta `htmlspecialchars` em torno dos dados do cliente.

Comment: Onde coloca o htmlspecialchars?